# PHP sort array results descending from a value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

so i am using Google Maps api and checking some locations distances with it.

I am using a while and i am constructing a json encode( for a mobile app )

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$lats = array("47.070611", "47.114438", "47.166981", "47.259799", "47.073114");
$long = array("21.921930", "21.937037", "21.950941", "22.002783", "21.958194");
$locations = array();
while($x <= count($lats)) {
    usleep(200000);
    $origin="47.072222, 21.921111";
    $desti="$lats[$x], $long[$x]"; 

    //replace the spaces with "+"
    $address1 = str_replace(' ', '+', $origin);
    $address2 = str_replace(' ', '+', $desti);

    //use concatenation as answered by @geocodezip
    $routes=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='.$address1.'&destination='.$address2.'&alternatives=true&sensor=false'))->routes;

    //sort the routes based on the distance
    usort($routes,create_function('$a,$b','return intval($a->legs[0]->distance->value) - intval($b->legs[0]->distance->value);'));

    //print the shortest distance
    $dist = $routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;
    $loc = array();
    if (empty($dist)) {
    }else{
        $loc = array('km'=>$dist);

        array_push($locations, $loc);
    }

    $x++;

}

print '{"distanta":'.json_encode($locations).'}';
?>
```

The result of this will be :

```
{"distanta":[{"km":"6.9 km"},{"km":"2.3 km"},{"km":"7.2 km"},{"km":"4.3 km"}]}
```

But i want to sort the result so the first value in array will be the lowest and the last value in array to be the highest ( DESCENDING )

I want to achive this :

```
{"distanta":[{"km":"2.3 km"},{"km":"4.3 km"},{"km":"6.9 km"},{"km":"7.2 km"}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated , i'm a newbie in php

Comment: What version of PHP are you using that you still use `create_function` instead of function expressions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you just want to reverse the order of the sort, swap the `$a` and `$b` arguments to the comparison function. But the result you say you want is not the reverse of the result you get, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the first value is lowest, that would be _ascending_, not _descending_.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

- Store pure numbers (distances) in `$locations` array:

  ```
  $dist = $routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;
  if (!empty($dist)) {
    array_push($locations, $loc);
  }
  ```
- After all distances are calculated (i.e. outside of your `while` loop), [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the `$locations` array numerically:

  ```
  sort($locations, SORT_NUMERIC);
  ```
- Then, change the array to an array of arrays, including `km` keys:

  ```
  foreach ($locations as &$loc) {
    $loc = array('km' => $loc);
  }
  ```
- Finally, use `json_encode()` as you do already:

  ```
  print '{"distanta":'.json_encode($locations).'}';
  ```

Comment: `empty(!$dist)` should be `!empty($dist)`.

Comment: @Barmar, of course, thx! It was a blind typo; it's late in Ukraine, I should better go to bed now ))

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT]
Sorry, I didn't read your code carfully enough, but this WILL work. I've tried it.
Put `usort($locations, function($a, $b) {return $a['km']-$b['km'];});` before your print on the last line and see for yourself!

---[old post, which is wrong]---
What you are trying to do is actually to sort your array **ascending**. This can easily be achived with `asort($locations)`. (This doesn't work)

Comment: `asort` doesn't let you provide a custom comparison function.

Comment: `$locations` is a multidimensional array, `asort` won't work for it.